# Django REST Framework validation function has different signature than Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a reservation system REST api in Django with a relatively simple model that will determine if a user has a valid membership in order for them to reserve a certain item. When creating a reservation, I have a simple validator written like this:

```
def validate_member(value):
    """
    Validator for a user in a reservation. Will throw a ValidationError if the user does not have an
    updated membership.
    """
    if not valid_membership(value):
        raise ValidationError("User does not have a valid membership!")
```

This validation is run on the foreign key field in the reservation table, which is written as such:

```
    # The gear item in the reservation
    gear_item = models.ForeignKey(Entry,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  null=True,
                                  help_text="The gear item being reserved.",
                                  validators=[validate_entry]
                                  )
```

The serializer for this model is written as a ModelSerializer, like such:

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = "__all__"
```

This design works fine for queries in the REST API, but fails for any modifications in the admin console, with the error: `'int' object has no attribute 'rentable'`

It seems that validating a foreign key in the admin console passes the primary key integer into the `value` parameter of the validation function, while the REST API passes in the entire object. Is there a workaround for this, or should I expect to not use the admin console at all due to this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution/work around for this would be overriding your admin console's form. 
I think [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) code snippet will be enough for you to handle your specific field and it's validation.